# Why I cannot open this Solution, I installed SDK version 7.0.203 and the Visual Studio I'm using is 2019 Community?

Tags: .net, sdk, visual-studio-2019

Beginner Level here, Every time I open the solution of Theory_v_Practice, I always see this error:
The project file cannot be opened. Version 7.0.203 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.4.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.11.2.50704. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.
[Error Pop UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU8I3.png)

I try to add a global.json to the project in order to add my .NET SDK 7.0.203.
So that it will see to it in the project folder because I cannot seem to find the global.json on C:\Users[username]\global.json.
[path folder of C:\Users[username]\global.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1HBR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Either upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 or downgrade the project to .NET 6.

I would go with the former if at all possible as downgrading the project could break things if it depends on something not available in .NET 6.

Comment: Yes it works, after I downgrade the project to .NET6.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @joshlipian Please mark the answer as accepted as it solved your problem.